# Doctrine2 ORM - Error using getResult

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using DoctrineORM and its querybuilder to update some data in my mySQL database. Look at my code below, I cannot spot the mistake.

```
public function update($id, Request $request){

    $em = new em();
    // fetch the document to be updated
    $updatedDocument = $em->getEm()->find('backend\resources\entities\Document', $id);
    $document = $request->request->all();

    $translator = new Translator('de_de');
    $validator = new Validation\Validator($translator, $document, $this->rules);

    if($validator->passes()){
        $updatedDocument->setTitle($document['title']);
        $updatedDocument->setWorkflow($document['workflow']);
        $updatedDocument->setDocClass($document['docClass']);

        $em->getEm()->persist($document);
        $em->getEm()->flush();

        $response = json_encode($document);
        return new Response($response, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'json'));
    }

    $response = json_encode(array('Error' => 'Could not be updated.'));
    return new Response($response, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'json'));

}
```

Now when I try to call this function I get this message:

> Warning: require(/tmp/__CG__backendresourcesentitiesUser.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/htdocs/w00ebb23/fokus/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 207
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/tmp/__CG__backendresourcesentitiesUser.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:..') in /www/htdocs/w00ebb23/fokus/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 207

I have to add that function with nearly the same content but for different entities work well. But this one doesn't.
A simple find by Id works fine when I use getArrayResult instead of getResult or getSingleResult. Any ideas what could be the error?

Comment: try to clean the server cache, proxy/metadata cache

Comment: This looks strange:  $em = new em(); Normally you would pull this sort of stuff from the container or use getDoctrine()

Comment: @Cerad This em() is a simple entityManager Helper-Class I created ... That does work at other places, too.

Comment: @Rufinus How do I clean the server cache? This application is intended to be used on a simple webhost ...

Comment: @RajK. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#clearing-the-cache

Comment: But can this be used on a shared host?